# Does ActiveMQ support NTLM authentication?

Tags: activemq-classic, ntlm

New to ActiveMQ and didn’t find any information whether ActiveMQ supports NTLM authentication or not by explicitly searching for documentation related to configuring it to use NTLM.

Could anyone please advise where I can find any information about supported authentication types by ActiveMQ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveMQ does not support NTLM out of the box. However, ActiveMQ integrates with JAAS and supports pluggable login modules so you could theoretically still get the support you need.